# GridView scrolling depends on target sdk version?

Tags: android, gridview

I don't understand why it happens and how to figure out where is the problem.

Really weird behavior. If I set `android:targetSdkVersion="16"` in manifest,  `GridView` scroll lag showing up. Without it, if only `android:minSdkVersion="8"` defined, smooth scroll.

Testing on device with Android 4.0.4.

I have some nested `LinearLayout`s like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
/>
```

And one column `GridView` inside it:

```
<GridView android:id="@+id/grid_0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="1"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/black"
    android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="false"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
/>
```

It contains only 15 `ImageView`s. And part of code from `ImageAdapter` used for `GridView`:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        if(largeScreen)
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(getPixels(128), getPixels(72), Gravity.CENTER));
        else
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(getPixels(64), getPixels(36), Gravity.CENTER));
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(images[position]); // images - Integer drawables array
    imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    boolean contains = false; // little for-loop here
    if(contains == 0)
        imageView.setAlpha(1.0f);
    else
        imageView.setAlpha(0.3f);
    }
    return imageView;
}

private int getPixels(int dipValue){
    int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dipValue, metrics);
    return px;
}
```